# Split without some spaces

Tags: javascript, split

Good morning,

If I have a string:

```
"@Hello(first second), one two"
```

And I want an array:

```
["@Hello(first second)", "one", "two"]
```

How I can do this?

Thanks,

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: By what logic would you convert that string into that array?  If you were to tell someone how to do it, what steps would you give them?  Those steps would be the starting point for the code you use to automate that process.

Comment: What do you mean by "without same spaces"? What are they the same as? Did you mean "without **some** spaces"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.split()` with `RegExp` `/\s(?!\w+\))/` to match space character not followed by word characters followed by closing parenthesis ")"

```
var str = "@Hello(first second), one two";
var res = str.split(/\s(?!\w+\))/);
console.log(res);
```

Alternatively you can use `.match()` with `RegExp` `/@\w+\(\w+\s\w+(?=\))\)|\w+(?=\s|$)/g` to match "@" followed by one or more word characters followed by "(" followed by word characters followed by space character followed by word characters followed by closing parenthsis ")" or word characters followed by space or end of string

```
var str = "@Hello(first second), one two";
var res = str.match(/@\w+\(\w+\s\w+(?=\))\)|\w+(?=\s|$)/g);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks. The solution for my case is use the split with the RegExp /\s(?!\w+\))/